# gallerys don`t work in my wordpress-site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, gallery

i have a problem with almost every gallery-plugin... they don`t work on my homepage,

check:

http://ntm.at/r0sa/?page_id=116

does anyone know what to do?
is something wrong with my php or css files?

Thank you!

Comment: Error: TypeError: jQuery(...).nggSlideshow is not a function
Source File: http://ntm.at/r0sa/?page_id=116
Line: 158. It seems that you haven't implemented it fully.

Comment: oh thanks, but what should i do now??

Comment: Read the plugin manual and try again.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too localized, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it but I think this error is because jQuery is being included twice on the page (once locally and once with googleapi).

In the header block you have.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ntm.at/r0sa/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
```

In the body block you have.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

One needs to be removed.

Comment: that`s an idea... but how can i remove it? should i delete this line in sidebar.php: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> ?

Comment: you need to delete one or the other, I'll have to leave that to you. I've updated my answer though

Comment: thanks for your help and i think it`s the solution... but when i click on sidebar.php i can only see ONE line looking like this, in the header block i see nothing like this... where did you found that?

Comment: I looked at the source of you page, that's the best I can do, I can't see the content of your php files. If you use some sort of IDE for development you should easily be able to search for it.

Comment: ok, so i deleted jquery from my wp-includes-folder, but it`s still not working... if i delete the googleapi- one, it works, but then the sidebar is not visible any more, because it needs jquery... have i done something wrong?

Comment: You may need to make another question for this issue. I would guess that whatever you have in your sidebar should be in a $(document).ready(); block

Comment: ok, i will ask otherwise- but you were close to the solution, thank you therefore!